# Auto-completar html en archivo php en Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, html5, vscode

Como indico quiero saber si es posible configurar visual studio code o si existe un plugin para eso, que permita utilizar el auto-completar de html en una archivo php ya que he notado que visual studio no tiene esta funcion como la tiene atom. y es un poco canson tener que escribir todo (class, placeholder etc) y lo mismo con las ayudas de bootstrap, cuando el archivo está en codigo php pasa eso, la unica forma de poder corregir esto es cambiando el lenguaje de programación con Ctrl k m, a html. se puede hacer esto de forma automatica que el propio editor se de cuenta de que lenguaje se está utilizando y habilite esos auto-completar?

Answer (score 1):

Este [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) me ha ayudado con eso. Pero en caso de que no funcione, o no puedas descargarlo. En la barra inferior, debería salir un texto con el lenguaje actual inferido apartir de la extensión del archivo. En tu caso, PHP. Podrías cambiarlo por HTML, aunque eso haría que el intellisense se apagara para PHP.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias de verdad... era justo lo que necesitaba ya me aparecen las ayudas (las más genéricas), en html y en php aparecieron unas ayuditas extras y cositas similares  TSLin... te agradezo.